Can Dirichlet eigenvalue and Neumann eigenvalue on disk coincide?
Let $D\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the unit disk. Consider the eigenvalue problem $-\Delta u=\lambda u$ in $D$. We know the Dirichlet eigenvalues are:
$\lambda_{0,k}=j_{0,k}^2$, $k\geq1$ (simple) and $\lambda_{n,k}=j_{n,k}^2$, $n,k\geq1$ (double);
while the Neumann eigenvalues are:
$\mu_{0,k}=(j^\prime_{0,k})^2$, $k\geq1$ (simple) and $\mu_{n,k}=(j^\prime_{n,k})^2$, $n,k\geq1$ (double).
Here, $j_{n,k}$ is the $k$-th zero of the Bessel function $J_n$ and $j^\prime_{n,k}$ is the $k$-th zero of $J^\prime_n$ (the derivative of Bessel function $J_n$). My question is that can Dirichlet eigenvalue and Neumann eigenvalue on disk coincide? Or equivalent, can $\lambda_{n,k}=\mu_{m,l}$ for some $n,m\geq 0$ and $k,l\geq1$?
We already know by the property of Bessel function that $\lambda_{0,k}\neq \mu_{0,k}$, $k\geq 1$ and $\lambda_{n,k}\neq \mu_{n,k}$, $n,k\geq1$. A little weak question is that can $\lambda_{0,m}=\mu_{n,k}$ for some $n,m,k\geq1$? Essentially, if $J_0$ and $J_n^\prime$ have no any common zeros, we are done. But I can't find a reference on this property.
Any help will be appreciated a lot.
